# Structure declaration with a pointer to it

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am studying structures in C from K&R book and encountered this:

```
struct{
    int len;
    char *str
} *p;
```

I am confused by this, because where the name of the struct variable should be, they have given a pointer `*p`. Can anyone please help me here? What does this declaration mean?

Comment: if the answer below helped you, please accept it by pressing the V next to it. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This declaration is a pointer to a struct which is composed of 2 fields — an `int` and a `char*`. This struct doesn't have a name and if you want to declare another pointer of the same struct, you will have to write it again.

Notice you can write something like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
int data1;
char data2;
};
```

This will define a new struct type which you can use later like this to declare a variable: `struct MyStruct myVar;`. The difference from what you wrote is that this struct doesn't declare a new variable but a new type since the struct in my example has a name and yours does not.

Another option is to use a `typedef` and give this struct a name and then you can use the name you have given it to declare more variables of that type.

You can read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef   in the "Simplifying a declaration" section.